# how to put json data within HTML

Tags: ajax

hi
i want to know how to put the json data into html 
is there a tag or what and is it put under body?

```
`["book":

        {
        "title":"JavaScript, the Definitive Guide",
        "publisher":"O'Reilly",
        "author":"David Flanagan",
        "cover":"/images/cover_defguide.jpg",
        "blurb":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."
            },


        {
        "title":"DOM Scripting",
        "publisher":"Friends of Ed",
        "author":"Jeremy Keith",
        "cover":"/images/cover_domscripting.jpg",
        "blurb":"Praesent et diam a ligula facilisis venenatis."
            },

        {
        "title":"DHTML Utopia: Modern Web Design using JavaScript & DOM",
        "publisher":"Sitepoint",
        "author":"Stuart Langridge",
        "cover":"/images/cover_utopia.jpg",
        "blurb":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."

    }
]`
```

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5

  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    var addrField = document.getElementById('myDiv');

    var card = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
    addrField.value = card.places.place.name.value;
    }
  };

xmlhttp.open("GET","HTMLPage3.htm",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You would need to produce HTML by iterating over the elements of the array. If you are using jQuery there is a template addin that can make this simple. Otherwise, you would need to do it through standard JavaScript.

Comment: @Smirkin Gherkin  i not using jQuery ....what you mean by iterating over the element ...cause i will be using this html url in the ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not valid JSON. The `book` property is not correctly defined. You could use the `<script>` tag to store this in your HTML document and ensure you have fixed this JSON or you will probably get javascript errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var books = [
    {
        "title":"JavaScript, the Definitive Guide",
        "publisher":"O'Reilly",
        "author":"David Flanagan",
        "cover":"/images/cover_defguide.jpg",
        "blurb":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."
    },
    {
        "title":"DOM Scripting",
        "publisher":"Friends of Ed",
        "author":"Jeremy Keith",
        "cover":"/images/cover_domscripting.jpg",
        "blurb":"Praesent et diam a ligula facilisis venenatis."
    },
    {
        "title":"DHTML Utopia: Modern Web Design using JavaScript & DOM",
        "publisher":"Sitepoint",
        "author":"Stuart Langridge",
        "cover":"/images/cover_utopia.jpg",
        "blurb":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."
    }
];
</script>
```

Now you can loop through the elements of this array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    var book = books[i];
    alert(book.title);
}
```

Comment: okay...if i have to use ajax and this json.html url i got to put it in xmlhttp.open("GET","json.htm",true);, will i able able to retrieve title and publisher ...how shld i code it

Comment: @cutexxbaby, once you fetch the response from the server you could convert it to a json object using the eval method: `var books = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);`. Then you can loop through the `books` object as I showed in my answer.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov can show me how ?cause this is my time in doing ajax and i never learn before

Comment: @cutexxbaby, here's a good article which should illustrate how to use AJAX: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov i not using php ....cause i do something similiar it give me syntax error..i will add in my ajax you help me see why

Comment: @cutexxbaby, that's not PHP, it's javascript.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov but i thought it var url = "get_data.php";
the php does mean it is using php...or i just change the this to my html which container my json data...darin you can see i add in my ajax function in the first

Comment: @cutexxbaby, yes you can change this url to a HTML page.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov arh?what i mean was that the json data right i put in the html page so i use that page url and put in the xmlhttp.open("GET","json.htm",true); will it work that only title and publisher will be retrieve ?
another is that did you see the ajax function tat i put up ...can you tell me why is there sytnax error